# XSLT for-each of a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML structure residing within a **namespace**:

```
<School>
  <SchoolInfo>
    <SchoolName>The Big School</SchoolName>
    <Opened>2008</Opened>
    <SchoolID>SCH1122</SchoolID>
    <Geograpics>
      <Location>London</Location>
      <PostCode>ZZ11 1ZZ</PostCode>
    </Geographics>
  </SchoolInfo>
  <Pupil>
    <Name>Tom</Name>
    <LastName>Jones</LastName>
    <Class>12B</Class>
    <Age>16</Age>
  </Pupil>
  <Pupil>
    <Name>Steve</Name>
    <LastName>Jobs</LastName>
    <Class>09A</Class>
    <Age>17</Age>
  </Pupil>
  <Pupil>
    <Name>Joe</Name>
    <LastName>Blogs</LastName>
    <Class>13A</Class>
    <Age>15</Age>
  </Pupil>
</School>
```

Using XSLTl I wish to create a PSV which looks like the following structure:
(SchoolID|Location|Name|Class|Age)

```
SCH1122|London|Tom|12B|16
SCH1122|London|Steve|09A|17
SCH1122|London|Joe|13A|15
```

Is this possible using XSLT and how would I go about this?

Code so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:x="NamespaceHere"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:cs="urn:cs"
exclude-result-prefixes="cs x msxsl" >

<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="x:SchoolID">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:PostCode">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:Name">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:Class">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:Age">
    <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="x:Message"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="x:School">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="x:SchoolInfo/x:SchoolID"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="x:SchoolInfo/x:Geographics/x:PostCode"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="x:Pupil/x:Name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="x:Pupil/x:Class"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="x:Pupil/x:Age"/>
    <xsl:text>&#0010;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works when I have only one pupil however when I get multiple pupils the output becomes like the following:

> SCH1122|London|London|Tom|Steve|12B|09A|16|17

Comment: So far I've got it to output the PSV in the correct order however I am completely stumped when it comes to processing each Pupil individually, so any guidance on how to loop on each Pupil while still having access to the nodes outside of the Pupil would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please post your code so far?

Comment: Code added now :) - I am adapting the code due to sensitivity of the actual document I am working with however that code should work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing your `match="x:School"` to:

```
<xsl:template match="x:School">
  <xsl:variable name="parent" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="x:Pupil">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$parent/x:SchoolInfo/x:SchoolID"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$parent/x:SchoolInfo/x:Geographics/x:PostCode"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="x:Name"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="x:Class"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="x:Age"/>
    <xsl:text>&#0010;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, didn't expect it to be so simple! Thanks alot.